# How to export/save the Android keystore files from MAC

Tags: macos, export, keystore

I am using MAC visual studio for xamarin forms app development. I am trying to take a back up for my android keystore files.

I found the keystore files at **/Users/[username]/Library/Developer/Xamarin/Keystore/** in my MAC using keystore explorer. How can I export or save the keystore files from here? Copy/paste, drag and drop and export options are not working.

Anyone, please tell me a way to export the keystore files from MAC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the path of my keystore folder **/Users/[username]/Library/Developer/Xamarin/Keystore/**. I can view the folder through `keystore explorer`. But when using the `finder` to open the keystore location the `Library` folder is not showing in `[username]` folder.

**So I go to the settings and check the `Show Library Folder` option. And now I can copy and paste keystore files.**